# Find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{s}{s^2-6s+9}$

Tags: laplace-transform

It is easy to see that $\frac{s}{s^2-6s+9}=\frac{s}{(s-3)^2}$ and now I want to use use the convolution integral for $s\cdot \frac{1}{(s-3)^2}$. So I get this integral:
$$\int_0^t \delta '(\tau)\cdot \tau e^{3\tau}d\tau$$ Which I din't know how to compute. Is this the correct reasoning at all?

Comment: It is not easy to see that $\frac{s}{s^2-6s+10}=\frac{s}{(s-3)^2}$.

Comment: Correct. Edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this table](http://integral-table.com/downloads/LaplaceTable.pdf) for example:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{s}{s^2-6s+9}=e^{3t}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{s+3}{s^2}
=e^{3t}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac1s+\frac3{s^2}\right)=(1+3t)e^{3t}$$

Comment: I don't understand the step taken to get it written by $e^{3t}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{s+3}{s^3}$, or refer me to a line in your link.

Comment: @UdiBehar Translation formula (2nd in the table): the (direct) transform of $e^{at}f(t)$ is $F(s-a)$.